# Chance of having score of 63

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Assume a batsman has an equal chance of getting a score of 1,2,3,4 and 6 and that he has 100% chance of eventually having a score greater than 63. What is the probability of the batsman having exactly a score of 63. For example if the batsman is on a total of 62, then there is only 0.1667 chance of him getting 63. What is the chance assuming his starting total is 0?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Missing information. Are the only possibilities that he scores 1,2,3,4,6 (what about 5) or can he score others (score 100 right off the bat)? Can we assume he stops after reaching a score of 63 or higher? (I.e. are we interested if at any point he had a score of 63?)

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, those are his only possible scores. Yes, we are interested if at any point he had a score of 63.

Comment: If he has a 100% chance of getting a score greater than 63, then he has a 0% chance of getting exactly 63.

Comment: @SuzuHirose yes, I do not have a background in probability and this seems out of my depth.

Comment: @EdwardJiang but what is his chance of getting 63 along the way?

Comment: I recommend a markov chain argument then, though if done with matrices it will be a 69x69 absorbing matrix.  Also you didn't answer about if he can score 5 on a turn.  If he can't then it would have been .2 chance to go from 62 to 63, not .1667.  Also @edward clearly he meant greater or equal

Comment: @Tom If that's what you mean, then I suggest you edit the question's wording to fit that.

Comment: @JMoravitz no he cannot get a 5, thanks for your help

Comment: Philip Hughes died last month, hit in the head by a cricket ball while on 63.  It was very big news in cricket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JMoravitz says, this is a Markov chain problem. But a $69\times 69$ matrix is unwieldy.

A good approximation is obtained by saying that, with every score $1,2,3,4,6$ equally likely, on average you will get $5$ scores in every total of $16\; (=1+2+3+4+6)$. E.g. if your first five scores were $1,2,3,4,6$ then you have gotten totals of $1,3,6,10,16$. Thus,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(63) &\approx & \dfrac{5}{1+2+3+4+6} = \dfrac{5}{16} = 0.3125
\end{eqnarray*}

The reason, I think this is a good approximation is that the further away from $0$ your target score is, the more even become the probabilities. That is, $P(1), P(2), P(3)$ might be quite varied, but $P(61), P(62), P(63)$ become almost the same and they would approach that limiting value above.

It's not hard to use that method in a more realistic model where scores $1,2,3,4,6$ are *not* equally likely. Let's say, we estimate their individual probabilities as:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(1) &=& 0.4 \\
P(2) &=& 0.2 \\
P(3) &=& 0.1 \\
P(4) &=& 0.25 \\
P(6) &=& 0.05
\end{eqnarray*}

Then our estimate would be:

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(63) &\approx & \dfrac{1}{ 1\times 0.4 + 2\times 0.2 + 3\times 0.1 + 4\times 0.25 + 6\times 0.05} = \dfrac{1}{2.4} \approx 0.4167
\end{eqnarray*}

The denominator there is the expected score on any one shot.

Answer (score 2):

Mick A's approximation is borne out by simulation.   Checking if 63 is reached at some point  in the cumulative sums of a sample from $\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 \}$, for one million possible samples, is a one-liner in R:

```
table(replicate(10^6, 63 %in% cumsum(sample(c(1,2,3,4,6), 63, TRUE))))
```

and this returns for me

```
 FALSE   TRUE 
687399 312601
```

Note that this depends on 63 being large compared to the possible scores.  For example the probability of eventually reaching 1 is 0.2, the probability of eventually reaching 2 is 0.24 (your sequence has to start with 2 or with 1, 1), and so on.  But apparently by the time you get to 63 this washes out.